# Group By ID, return MIN date and include Zipcode at time of MIN date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The Dataframe contains:

```
    >> df
    ID       DATE     ZIPCODE
    196512  1/1/2017  17961  
    196512  3/1/2016  96512 
    196512  2/1/2017  34521
    196512  9/23/2017 85687
    196795  3/2/2017  28978
    196795  7/3/2016  98362
    196795  9/2/2016  21345
    196795  1/1/2015  03452
```

My current python pandas code is:

`df1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID","ZIPCODE"],values=["DATE"],aggfunc=min)`

This code kind of gets what I want, however, you can see in my example that by creating a pivot table on ID and ZIPCODE, I have to manually assess my output afterward to figure out each ID's earliest Date with the zipcode of the MIN Date.

The results I am looking for would be:

```
    ID      Date      ZIPCODE
    196512  3/1/2016   96512
    196795  1/1/2015   03452
```

Because I am seeking to find each ID's earliest date and the associated zipcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True)

res = df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].idxmin()]

print(res)

#        ID       DATE  ZIPCODE
# 1  196512 2016-01-03    96512
# 7  196795 2015-01-01     3452
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert to datetime format first , then we using `drop_duplicates` after `sort_values`

```
df.assign(DATE=pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)).sort_values('DATE').drop_duplicates('ID')
Out[207]: 
       ID       DATE  ZIPCODE
7  196795 2015-01-01     3452
1  196512 2016-03-01    96512
```